# Magento 2.3 invalid form key. please refresh the page

Tags: magento2

while submit customer registration form i got this error. can anyone help me to fix this issue!

[image]

Comment: can you clear the cache and provide proper permission to var folder and try again.

Comment: have you changed anything in the template files in your Magento installation?

Comment: i already clear the cache from var/cache directory..and given the 777 permission to my shop root directory..

Comment: i didn't change any template files during installation

Comment: newly started to installing magento 2.3.2...i tried to create customer account suddenly i got this issue!

Comment: Have you cleared browser cache and cookies for the site after increasing max input variables

Answer (score 3):

1. Log in to your website server using ssh
2. Go to the folder containing `php.ini` and open this file by vi
3. Edit the value of `max_input_vars to 5000` (or create it if it doesn’t exist yet). Then, press ESC key and type :wq to save the file.
4. Restart your Mamp or Apache. Now you can create customer without any problem.

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Hi, Anas Mansuri !

Comment: i tried these steps..but not working for me

Comment: i increased 'max_input_vars to 5000' and saved it..restart my apache server too..but not working.. is there anyother way to fix it.

Comment: i think set try with double.

Comment: check with this table `core_config_data` `path='web/cookie/cookie_domain' and web/cookie/cookie_path` , if exist than remove in this table.

Comment: I have to put it much higher. And every magento upgrade wipes my file so I have the problem again and must remember

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento in local then check the table 'core_config_data' and find web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url in 'path' column and change their value http://localhost/[project-name]/  to http://127.0.0.1/[project-name]/

This works for me.
Just Try it...